# Modifying properties of a meshed element of a solid rod in ABAQUS 6.10 using Python scripting

Tags: python, abaqus

Problem Statement:

I am modelling a solid rectangular bar of 1 meter with its one end fixed and the other end free (a cantilever) in ABAQUS 6.10. The bar has elastic and homogeneous material properties. I need to determine the first 10 natural frequencies of the structure and store it in an array (which I will be needing it for some other use- not relevant here) using Python script.

**Question 1:** *How do I retrieve the first ten natural frequencies and store it in an array in Python?*

As you will comprehend that this model only contains one part and that has been meshed using homogenous solid elements. For some reason, I need to change the young's modulus only for specific elements in the meshed part.

**Question 2:** *How can I do it using Python script? Is creation of an orphaned mesh and changing its properties using Python script relevant to the problem?*

I would be glad to receive an answer!

Comment: if at all possible you should work with the geometry. Partition the geometry so you can assign a separate section / material properties to the region you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @agentp. You're right! I just partitioned the portions to which I needed to assign a different material property. In my problem it was easier partition rather than create a separate part.